# Json parser error? Amazon API incorrect JSON response?

Tags: java, json, parsing, amazon-web-services

So here is the code I use to parse the amazon JSON response for my inventory of products.

```
 ListInventorySupplyResponse response = client.listInventorySupply(request);
  ResponseHeaderMetadata rhmd = response.getResponseHeaderMetadata();

  String responseJSON = response.toJSON();
  JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

  try {
                json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(responseJSON);
```

It worked for a week, and then I got this error today.

```
Unexpected token VALUE(-1) at position 5948.
```

looking through the response JSON. I put it in a JSON validator (http://jsonlint.com/)

jsonlint told me that the response I was getting was not correct json! Here was the error

```
  {
                    "SellerSKU": "zz",
                    "FNSKU": "B006T5BLTO",
                    "ASIN": "B006T5BLTO",
                    "Condition": "NewItem",
                    "TotalSupplyQuantity": 92,
                    "InStockSupplyQuantity": 44,
                    "EarliestAvailability": {
                        "TimepointType": "DateTime",
                        "DateTime": 2015-01-13T09: 00: 00Z
                    },
                    "SupplyDetail": {
                        "member": [

                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "SellerSKU": "yyC",
                    "FNSKU": "B00IHMDJ7Y",
                    "ASIN": "B00IHMDJ7Y",
                    "Condition": "NewItem",
                    "TotalSupplyQuantity": 63,
                    "InStockSupplyQuantity": 63,
                    "EarliestAvailability": {
                        "TimepointType": "Immediately"
                    },
                    "SupplyDetail": {
                        "member": [

                        ]
                    }
                },

    Parse error on line 398:
  ...    "DateTime": 2015-01-13T09: 00: 00Z 
     ----------------------^
    Expecting '}', ',', ']'
```

As you can see, for some reason most of products are available immediately but one is not and Amazon sends me a "datetime" for when it is. However they dont put the date time in quotes making it an invalid JSON.

Is it me? Is it them? How do I handle this. My program doesnt need this part of the JSON but I dont know how to take this field out or tell the parser to "skip over it" so that it can parse the rest of the fields minus this one incorrect field that I dont care about anyway.

Thanks!

Comment: looks to me like that the `DateTime` value should be in quotes

Comment: It should! But the issue is that this is the response that amazon is giving back to me. I have no power to change it b4 the parser. 

Actually brainwave maybe I can try some .toString.replace manipulation and replace everything after the "dateformat" with some sort of string

Comment: Its just so bizarre that the JSON amazon is giving me is incorrect.... lol

Comment: Thanks for looking. If you see anything let me know! Its possible its just some weird thing that my java object is doing so im going to double check in the scratchpad. might call amazon if its their problem lol, I'll try to implement some string manipulation fix in my code